# How to specify the "Mode" and "UpdateSourceTrigger" in my "CustomControl's" markup?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, custom-controls, devexpress

Have a have `CustomControl` that consists of a `ComboBox` and a `Button`.

The binding works fine, but the `Set` only happens on `LostFocus` it seems.

This is my CustomControl's markup:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type cba:CustomComboBoxEditView}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cba:CustomComboBoxEditView}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="ComboBoxEdit"
                                      Height="Auto" 
                                      Width="Auto"
                                      Grid.Column="0"
                                      ImmediatePopup="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ImmediatePopup}"
                                      AutoComplete="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=AutoComplete}"
                                      IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsEnabled}"
                                      Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Visibility}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource}"
                                      DisplayMember="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DisplayMember}"
                                      ValueMember="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ValueMember}"
                                      EditValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=EditValue}"/>

                    <dxe:ButtonEdit ShowText="False"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    AllowDefaultButton="False"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsEnabled}"
                                    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Visibility}">
                        <dxe:ButtonInfo x:Name="PART_btnView" GlyphKind="Search" ToolTipService.ToolTip="View" />
                    </dxe:ButtonEdit>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For a normal `ComboBoxEdit`. the binding would look as follow:

`EditValue="{Binding Path=SomePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"`

This is what my markup looks like when i use the `CustomControl`:

```
<cba:CustomComboBoxEditView Name="someName"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeSource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     DisplayMember="DisplayMember"
                     ValueMember="ValueMember"
                     EditValue="{Binding Path=SomePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=False}"/>
```

1. How to specify the "Mode" and "UpdateSourceTrigger" in my `CustomControl's` markup?
2. What am i doing wrong in my `CustomControl` for the `Set` to only happen on `LostFocus`?

**EDIT:**

Code behind for `CustomControl`:

```
public class CustomComboBoxEditView : Control
{
    #region Fields

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImmediatePopupProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoCompleteProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueMemberProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EditValueProperty;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SystemAppEntityViewCodeProperty;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor.
    /// </summary>
    static CustomComboBoxEditView()
    {
        // Initialize as lookless control
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView)));

        // Initialize dependency properties
        ImmediatePopupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImmediatePopup",
           typeof(bool), typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        AutoCompleteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AutoComplete", typeof(bool),
           typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object),
           typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        DisplayMemberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMember", typeof(string),
           typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        ValueMemberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ValueMember", typeof(string),
           typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        EditValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EditValue", typeof(object),
           typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        SystemAppEntityViewCodeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SystemAppEntityViewCode", typeof(string),
           typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Custom Control Properties

    public bool ImmediatePopup
    {
         get { return (bool)GetValue(ImmediatePopupProperty); }
         set { SetValue(ImmediatePopupProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool AutoComplete
    {
         get { return (bool)GetValue(AutoCompleteProperty); }
         set { SetValue(AutoCompleteProperty, value); }
    }

    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public string DisplayMember
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayMemberProperty, value); }
    }

    public string ValueMember
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ValueMemberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueMemberProperty, value); }
    }

    public object EditValue
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(EditValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EditValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public string SystemAppEntityViewCode
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SystemAppEntityViewCodeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SystemAppEntityViewCodeProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You tried to update when your CustomControl loses focus, but what about the binding of the ComboBox inside your CustomControl?

Comment: @Markus I might have explained incorrect. It is currently updating on `LostFocus`, but i don't want it that way. Do i need to change the binding inside my `CustomControl`, so that it updates normal?

Comment: May be I explained it incorrect. I think your intention is to update it immediately (like UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged) but it does not work. If so, have a look inside the CustomControl and set UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged there additionally. But this is just an idea and I do not know anything what is inside your control. Perhaps you can have us a look into it.

Comment: @Markus Please see update. I added the code behind.

Comment: Hmmm.... I still have no clue if I am right, so sorry if this leads to nonsense. I would try this first in your CustomControls markup: `EditValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=EditValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` Next try would be `EditValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("EditValue", typeof(object), typeof(CustomComboBoxEditView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, null, null, false, UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around:

Register for the `PopupClosed Event` and then set the `Property`.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var btnComboBoxEdit = Template.FindName("ComboBoxEdit", this) as ComboBoxEdit;
        btnComboBoxEdit.PopupClosed +=new ClosePopupEventHandler(btnComboBoxEdit_PopupClosed);
    }

private void btnComboBoxEdit_PopupClosed(object sender, ClosePopupEventArgs e)
    {
        EditValue = e.EditValue;
    }
```